# Installing Java3D on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, java-3d

Sorry in advance if this is a really bad question, but I can't seem to find a recent enough tutorial on how to install Java3D on Eclipse 3.6.0 for Mac OSX 10.6.6. If anyone knows where a good tutorial is, or if you can give me instructions, please do so. Thanks!

Comment: When asking questions here, it is usually always a good idea to specify what you tried so far, and why it didn't work.

Comment: Oh, sorry. So far, I have downloaded the Java3D api from [link](https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductRef=java3d-1.5.1-oth-JPR@CDS-CDS_Developer) and put the jars in my \System\Library\Java\Extensions. Other than that I haven't really done anything because I don't know where to start. Please help!

Comment: Eclipse might say there is an access restriction, but you CAN compile  and run it, if you installed it correctly by then.

Comment: To go a little off topic; java 3D has largly been abandoned by sun (which is probably why there isn't much recent stuff you can find), you might want to consider JMonkey which is similar to java3D (scene graph based, object orientated) but is being very actively maintained (plus I use it so it must be good)

Answer (score 4):

To add the jar's to a **specific project's classpath**:

1. Right-click (or cmd-click on mac?) your project in the Project Explorer view and choose **Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries**.
2. Add the folder "\System\Library\Java\Extensions" by clicking the "Add External Class Folder..." button

**EDIT:**

I would suggest the following, given that

- you have the JDK (version 1.5.0 or higher) installed
- you have Eclipse for Java or Java EE developers installed (not Eclipse Classic for example)
- you can build a vanilla, HelloWorld Java application already

Basically, it sounds like you might not have added the Java 3D api's to your JRE. The download you linked to in your original question contains a help file named README-unzip.html, which is where I obtained the following instructions from:

> 1. Download java3d-1_5_1-XXX.zip to a temporary directory, for example,
>      "/tmp"
> 2. Unzip java3d-1_5_1-XXX.zip into "/tmp" as follows:
>
>    ```
>        cd /tmp
>        unzip java3d-1_5_1-*.zip
>    ```
>
>    This will create a "java3d-1_5_1-XXX" subdirectory in
>      /tmp where the downloaded files can be
>      found. The file you need for manual
>      installation is "j3d-jre.zip".
> 3. Unzip Java 3D 1.5.1 into the "jre" directory of your JDK. For
>      example, if your JDK is in
>      "/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_01/jre", you would
>      do the following:
>
>    ```
>        cd /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_01/jre
>        unzip /tmp/java3d-1_5_1-*/j3d-jre.zip
>    ```
>
>    Verify that the j3dcore.jar, j3dutils.jar, and vecmath.jar files
>      end up in
>      "/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_01/jre/lib/ext"

Comment: Thank you, but this didn't work. I would be grateful if you had any other ideas.

Comment: Just to ensure we're on the same wavelength here, when you say it didn't work, do you mean you can't seem to reference the Java3D api's in your Eclipse project? Are you able to create/compile Java projects in general? For example, are you unable to compile a class which references the Java3D class "com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.Box"?

Answer (score 2):

These threads might also be helpful:

- Java3d 1.5.2 on Macos http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9254447
- Java3D + Newer Eclipse Version http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2133747&tstart=0

From: August

Answer (score 0):

The previous instructions are NOT for installing java3d into Eclipse. In the same readme file it says: Users of IDEs such as NetBeans and Eclipse should consult the IDE's documentation to see how to add jar files and native libraries to their current project.

Comment: @torbinski's answer addresses that side of things.